# Bind click event to a collection of svg paths at runtime in angular 5

Tags: svg, binding, path, angular5

In my Angular 5 project I am trying to bind a click event to each of the paths of an svg object that gets dynamically loaded. I have successfully bound a click event to one path element using the following code:

```
constructor(private elemRef: ElementRef) { } 

mapEventInit() {
        this.elemRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.country')
        .addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this));
}  
onClick(event) {
        console.log(event.target.id);
}
```

The problem is that **querySelector** only lets me bind to the first element in the collection of elements with the .country class. **Is there a proper 'angular' way to do this or should I just use regular typescript**, as follows?

```
const pathCollection = document.querySelectorAll('.country');
for (let i = 0; i < pathCollection.length; i++) {
  pathCollection[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(this.id);
  });
}
```

Comment: The approach you should take is: add event listener to the parent (for paths) svg element, onclick check event.target to determine which path received the click

Comment: If you need help with actual code - share you code snippet (at least template snd component)